# LaTeX commands in Verbatim using fancyvrb and listings

Tags: beamer, fonts, listings, fancyvrb

I am trying to use LaTeX commands like `\textbf`, `\textit`, `\textcolor` in `fancyvrb` combined with `listings`. Especially I want to bold and color any text or entire blocks of Java code (not just keywords) at the same time.

So my `\lstset` options do not have keywordstyle set, so that I can bold, color any part of the code I want. I have the sample LaTeX code I am using below, but only the `\textit` command works. The `\textbf` command does not work. If I try to combine `\textbf` and `\textcolor` like

```
\textcolor!red|!\textbf!package com.test3;||
```

I get a whole bunch of errors. I am pasting my sample code below...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{bars}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaPlain}{ %
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts 
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for th
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding 
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen
fancyvrb=true,
fvcmdparams=textbf 1 textit 1,
}


\newenvironment{JavaCodePlain}
  { \VerbatimEnvironment%
    \lstset{style=JavaPlain}
    \begin{Verbatim} }
  { \end{Verbatim}  } 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \frametitle{Latex commands in Verbatim}
   \fvset{commandchars=\\\!\|}
   \begin{JavaCodePlain}
   \textbf!package com.test;|  // This does not become bold
   \textit!package com.test2;| //This is italicized
   \textcolor!red|!\textbf!package com.test3;|| //Whole bunch of errors

    public class Employee {
      ...
    }
  \end{JavaCodePlain}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define an optional argument for the Verbatim environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}%% monotype with bold variant  
\usetheme{bars}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaPlain}{ %
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts 
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for th
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding 
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen
fancyvrb=true,
}

\newcommand\Red[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newenvironment{JavaCodePlain}[1][]
  { \VerbatimEnvironment%
    \begin{Verbatim}[#1]}
  { \end{Verbatim}  } 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \frametitle{Latex commands in Verbatim}
   \begin{JavaCodePlain}[commandchars=\\!|]
   \textbf!package com.test;|  // This does not become bold
   \textit!package com.test2;| //This is italicized
   \Red!\textbf!package com.test3;|| //Whole bunch of errors

    public class Employee {
      ...
    }
  \end{JavaCodePlain}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, you should use a monotype font which has a bold variant like `beramono`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, Is there a way I can bold and color multiple lines (whole blocks of code) while still preserving the new lines. If I use the above method, it works for single lines, but for multiple lines, it removes the new lines and prints everything in one line.

Comment: Actually Herbert, you did not use \lstset{style=JavaPlain} in defining the new environment. I have more than one style and I want to chose the style when defining the environment.

Comment: I added the \lstset{style=JavaPlain} and it worked. Some how it did not work for the first time. I must have done something wrong.